# PHP-curl module disapers and comes back

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, php-curl, php-7.0

I have installed the curl module(7.47.0) for PHP and enabled the support for curl. 
But when i use it, the module sometimes disappers and then comes back again. I can see the same thing in my phpinfo(); Sometimes its there, and sometimes its not. The only thing im doing is reloading the page where its running.

PHP Version 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6

i have tried reinstalling php, curl and the curl mod but nothing helps. 
it still disappears and comes back again when reloading the site multiple times.

I have found out that i disables and enables all the time.

```
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Enabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Enabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Enabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Disabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Enabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Enabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Disabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Disabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Enabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Disabled
root@aahumv-miner01:/var/www/html# curl localhost/curl-check.php
Curl: Disabled
```

__

Comment: What does your apache error log say? Located: /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: @kenef it doesnt say anything actually, only a bunch of random things. Like sone undefined varialbes, but nothing about this issue.

Comment: Is this Digitalocean? Linode? Who provides your server?

Comment: i provide it, in my own datacenter. its self managed.

Comment: You may want to check this solution: https://www.gdgsoft.info/t/using-curl-with-php-7-solved/2669 since you're working with php v7. Some known bugs with various dll files.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with apache changing the PHP version between to different versions of php 7.0.. even though only one where activated in apache. 
A reboot helped-

Comment: Oh yea that's strange. I normally run sudo service apache2 restart after all installations or config changes and that makes things 'stick'. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: A service restart didnt do it, a machine restart did it